# Is there any way to enable pinch zoom and panning in noVNC

Tags: angular, canvas, novnc

I am using noVNC client in an angular app. but now I have got a requirement to enable pinch zoom and panning in mobile devices. panning works when we click on the hand icon in the control bar. but I want it to be enabled by default.

I tried to implementcustom pinch and zoom and panning. pinch and zoom worked. but when I try to click on a folder in the vnc desktop, then the folder did not open (because of the canvas zoom, the co-ordinates got different in remote and local canvas)